# Is CVE-2011-1571 fixed in tomcat?

Tags: linux, cve, appsec

I dont see any record of CVE-2011-1571 being fixed in tomcat based on ASF' security reports for tomcat itself. Usually they specify the CVE number and information about the fix. This was 3 years ago so i guess it has been fixed but when it has such a high vulnerability score i would still like to know as im planning to use this container in an environment where security is very important.

http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2011-1571&cid=2

also wondering about this CVE-2010-0557

Comment: It appears the vulnerabilities do not affect Tomcat, but affect IBM's Cognos Express product.  That is, Cognos Express contained a hard-code credential to access the Tomcat manager -> "IBM Cognos Express contains a default manager-level account password for the packaged Tomcat server".